# Cloud Run, when new deploying service is stopping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I realized that the existing server domain did not work because of the replace operation every time I did Cloud Run deploy. how can i prevent this? (If the app is in service)

It's not a long time, but I still want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cloud Run support for gradual rollouts and rollbacks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-gradual-rollouts-and-rollbacks):

> Cloud Run now allows you to have more control over the rollout of your
> changes. As always, any change to the configuration of a Cloud Run
> service creates a new revision, and by default, Cloud Run
> automatically rolls 100% to newly created revisions. But now you can
> also decide to manually split traffic between revisions, allowing you
> to gradually roll out revisions or roll back to an older revision.

Cloud Run release a new version of that service using the blue green deployment release model.Blue-Green deployments usually mean that you deploy the new version of your application alongside the current stable version and switch traffic to the new version.

[What is blue green deployment?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/devops/what-is-blue-green-deployment)

> Blue green deployment  is an application release model that gradually
> transfers user traffic from a previous version of an app or
> microservice to a nearly identical new release—both of which are
> running in production.  The old version can be called the blue
> environment while the new version can be known as the green
> environment. Once production traffic is fully transferred from blue to
> green, blue can standby in case of rollback or pulled from production
> and updated to become the template upon which the next update is made.

Cloud Run allows you to specify which revisions should receive traffic and to specify traffic percentages that are received by a revision. This feature allows you to rollback to a previous revision, gradually roll out a revision, and split traffic between multiple revisions.This [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration) describes how to use this feature to manage traffic to your Cloud Run revisions.